# Record-triggered flow: change execution path based on runtime context

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, queueable-apex

1. I have an Apex class that implements Queueable. It deletes records.
2. I have a record-triggered flow that runs on after delete of the
   records.

I want to prevent the flow from running (*or* performing its tasks) if the record was deleted by my Queueable. If the record is deleted via any other means, the flow should run.

My thought - Have a custom field on Object that can say whether it is deleted from queueable or standard UI/Other apex class. But the challenge is it is a delete operation so the field can't be set when I am doing it from queueable. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: The field can be set on a related object that will stick around / is not being deleted. This whole thing sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Queueable apex supports a UI page which deletes all record(type say workOrder) and recreates it. I have a staging object where I need to update the status field as deleted only if a user manually deletes the workorder. When user manually deletes the WO it uses the external id field on Wo to query all the staging record which has the same external id and update the status as deleted. In queue-able , however as I delete and recreate all WO , i dont want the to upsate the status to delete at that time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have time to test this, but here's my idea. Create an InvocableMethod that can be called by the flow. The Queueable can set a static variable to disable the flow.

```
public class DisableFlowAction {
    public static Boolean disabled = false;
    public class Request {
        @InvocableVariable public Boolean unusedProp;
    }
    @InvocableMethod(label='Disable Flow Action')
    public static Boolean[] respond(Request[] requests) {
        Boolean[] returnValue = new Boolean[0];
        for(Integer i = 0; i < requests.size(); i++) {
            returnValue.add(disabled);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Which your queuable can set:

```
DisableFlowAction.disabled = true;
```

And you can then check using an Apex Action and a Decision Element to abort early if the flag is set.

Comment: Thank you i will try this out and let know